# Vue component inside component renders table incorrectly

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I have 2 components.

1. Table Component
2. Row Component (Each row in the table)

The table component calls the row component inside the `<tbody>` tag for every row in the data.
But while rendering the rows are rendered first (outside the table tag) followed by the `<table>` tag.

See the example below.

```js
Vue.component('single-table-row', {
  props: {
    row: {
      type: Object
    }
  },
  template: `
    <tr>
    <td>{{row.id}}</td>
    <td>{{row.text}}</td>
    </tr>
  `
});

Vue.component('mytable', {
  props: {
    tabledata: {
      type: Object
    }
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      headers: ['Id', 'Text']
    }
  },
  computed: {
    table_rows: function () {
      return this.tabledata.data.rows;
    }
  }
});

var app3 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-3',
  data: {
    mydata: {
      data: {
        rows: [
          {
            id: 1,
            text: 'Sample 1'
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            text: 'Sample 2'
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            text: 'Sample 3'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app-3">
  <mytable v-bind:tabledata="mydata" inline-template>
    <div id="table_parent">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th v-for="header in headers">{{header}}</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <single-table-row :row=rows v-for="rows in table_rows" :key=rows.id>
          </single-table-row>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </mytable>
</div>
```

The output is rendered as :

```
<div id="table_parent">
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Sample 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Sample 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Sample 3</td>
    </tr>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Text</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Ideally it should have rendered the row component inside the `<tbody>` tag.
What am I missing here ?

Comment: Is this all your code?

Comment: this is the [mre] :)

Comment: The `mytable` component lacks a template - you should use something like `<table><single-table-row v-for="row in tableRows" :key="row.id" :tabledata="row" /></table>`

Comment: the `mytable` component has an inline template in the html

Comment: I can't figure out what you are missing but my sense is that I am not looking at the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `<tr is="single-table-row"` instead of `<single-table-row`.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats

This is because your template is directly in the HTML. The browser will parse it before Vue gets anywhere near it. Certain elements, such as `tbody`, have restrictions on what child elements they can have. Any elements that are not allowed will be torn out the table. By the time Vue gets involved they've already been moved.

```js
Vue.component('single-table-row', {
  props: {
    row: {
      type: Object
    }
  },
  template: `
    <tr>
    <td>{{row.id}}</td>
    <td>{{row.text}}</td>
    </tr>
  `
});

Vue.component('mytable', {
  props: {
    tabledata: {
      type: Object
    }
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      headers: ['Id', 'Text']
    }
  },
  computed: {
    table_rows: function () {
      return this.tabledata.data.rows;
    }
  }
});

var app3 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-3',
  data: {
    mydata: {
      data: {
        rows: [
          {
            id: 1,
            text: 'Sample 1'
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            text: 'Sample 2'
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            text: 'Sample 3'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app-3">
  <mytable v-bind:tabledata="mydata" inline-template>
    <div id="table_parent">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th v-for="header in headers">{{header}}</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr is="single-table-row" :row=rows v-for="rows in table_rows" :key=rows.id>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </mytable>
</div>
```